# MySQL: SELECTing by hash: is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, md5

I don't think it has too much sense. Although, this way you could hide the real static value from .php file, but keeping its hash value in php file for mysql query. The source of php file can't be reached from user's machine, but you have make backups of your files, and that static value is there. Selecting using hash of column would resolve this problem, I believe.

But, I didn't find any examples or documentation saying that it's possible to use such functions in queries (not for values in sql queries, but for columns to select).
Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to solve a non-existent problem.  Forgetting the Solution for a second... what is the problem you are trying to solve? e.g. it sounds like you are trying to make The Complicator's Gloves: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely slow query that simply selects all rows with an empty "column".

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(column) = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
```

If you're doing a lot of these queries, consider saving the MD5 hash in a column or index. Even better would be to do all MD5 calculations on the script's end - the day you're going to need an extra server for your project you'll notice that webservers scale a lot better than database servers. (That's something to worry about in the future, of course)

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that setting up your system this way won't actually solve any problem in your particular case. You are not making your system more secure doing this, you are just making it more convoluted.

The standard way to hide secret values from the source base is to store these secret values in a separate file, and never submit that file to source control or make a backup of it. Load the value of the secret by using php code and then work with the value directly in MySQL (one way to do this is to store a "config.php" file or something along that lines that just sets variables/constants, and then just php-include the file).

That said, I'll answer your question anyway.

MySQL actually has a wide-variety of hashing and encryption functions. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html

Since you tagged your question `md5` I'm assuming the function you're looking for is MD5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5

You select it just like this:

```
SELECT MD5(column) AS hashed_column FROM table
```

Then the value to compare to the hash will be in the column alias 'hashed_column'.

Or to select a particular row based on the hash:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(column) = 'hashed-value-to-compare'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a hash as a primary key:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (pk) VALUES (MD5('plain-value'));
```

Then you want to retrieve it by hash without knowing what its hash digest is:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE pk = MD5('plain-value');
```

Somehow this is supposed to provide greater security in case people steal a backup of your database and PHP code?  Well, it doesn't.  If I know the original plain-value and the method of hashing, I can find the data just as easily as if you didn't hash the value.

I agree with the comment from @scunliffe -- we're not sure exactly what problem you're trying to solve, but it sounds like this method will not solve it.

It's also inefficient to use an MD5 hash digest as a primary key.  You have to store it in a CHAR(32), or else UNHEX it and store it in BINARY(16).  Regardless, you can't use INT or even BIGINT as the primary key datatype.  The key values are more bulky, and therefore make larger indexes.

Also new rows will insert in an arbitrary location in the clustered index.  That's more expensive than adding new values to the end of the B-tree, as you would do if you used simple auto-incrementing integers like everyone else.